# vim search - not highlighting my destructor

Tags: vim, regex

I have a cpp file with a class definition. In the class definition, I also have an explicit destructor, like this -

```
class foo
{
    foo(){} // constructor
    ~foo(){} //destructor
    // more code here
};
```

I am looking at this file inside the vim editor. I wanted to navigate to the destructor, so, in normal mode, I type `/~foo`, but that failed to highlight the destructor.

I got the following errors -

```
E33: No previous substitute regular expression
E383: Invalid search string: ~foo
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape `~` like that `/\~foo`.